# Reading files with a BOM in Go

Tags: unicode, go, byte-order-mark

I need to read Unicode files that may or may not contain a byte-order mark. I could of course check the first few bytes of the file myself, and discard a BOM if I find one. But before I do, is there any standard way of doing this, either in the core libraries or a third party?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No standard way, IIRC (and the standard library would really be a wrong layer to implement such a check in) so here are two examples of how you could deal with it yourself.

One is to use a buffered reader above your data stream:

```
import (
    "bufio"
    "os"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    fd, err := os.Open("filename")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer closeOrDie(fd)
    br := bufio.NewReader(fd)
    r, _, err := br.ReadRune()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    if r != '\uFEFF' {
        br.UnreadRune() // Not a BOM -- put the rune back
    }
    // Now work with br as you would do with fd
    // ...
}
```

Another approach, which works with objects implementing the `io.Seeker` interface, is to read the first three bytes and if they're not BOM, `io.Seek()` back to the beginning, like in:

```
import (
    "os"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    fd, err := os.Open("filename")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer closeOrDie(fd)
    bom := [3]byte
    _, err = io.ReadFull(fd, bom[:])
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    if bom[0] != 0xef || bom[1] != 0xbb || bom[2] != 0xbf {
        _, err = fd.Seek(0, 0) // Not a BOM -- seek back to the beginning
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }
    // The next read operation on fd will read real data
    // ...
}
```

This is possible since instances of `*os.File` (what `os.Open()` returns) support seeking and hence implement `io.Seeker`.  Note that that's not the case for, say, `Body` reader of HTTP responses since you can't "rewind" it.  `bufio.Buffer` works around this feature of non-seekable streams by performing some buffering (obviously) — that's what allows you yo `UnreadRune()` on it.

Note that both examples assume the file we're dealing with is encoded in UTF-8.  If you need to deal with other (or unknown) encoding, things get more complicated.

Comment: The bufio approach worked, and I like that it considers the BOM as a single rune rather than a set of bytes.

Comment: @kostix cloud you explain how to derive the condition in the second approach?. Thanks

Comment: @Anuruddha, sorry, I failed to parse your question—in particular the "derive the condition" part which appears to be essential. Care to elaborate? May be in a few sentences.

Comment: @kostix the condition you used bom[0] != 0xef || bom[1] != 0xbb || bom[1] != 0xbf

Comment: @Anuruddha, oh there's an error in it: the last bit must check the byte at index 2: `bom[2] != 0xbf`. Still, I fail to interpret the "derive" in your question: to derive from what? May be start from reading [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8)? (Thanks for spotting the error; I'm going to fix it now).

Comment: @kostix thank's. I was confused because of the error you corrected and it use the OR operator. Shouldn't it be AND?

Comment: @Anuruddha, no, an UTF-8-encoded BOM is the three bytes with specific values in specific order, so the logic is "if any of the bytes in the sequence has a value it must not have at that position, that's not a BOM".

Comment: I like the bufio approach. Before reading this article I was doing a similar thing with a piped function because I hadn't realised I could pass a bufio reader on to the csv reader - that's very cool.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [utfbom](https://github.com/dimchansky/utfbom) package. It wraps `io.Reader`, detects and discards BOM as necessary. It can also return the encoding detected by the BOM.

Answer (score 4):

I thought I would add here the way to **strip** the **Byte Order Mark** sequence from a **string** -- rather than messing around with bytes directly (as shown above).

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    s := "\uFEFF is a string that starts with a Byte Order Mark"
    fmt.Printf("before: '%v' (len=%v)\n", s, len(s))

    ByteOrderMarkAsString := string('\uFEFF')

    if strings.HasPrefix(s, ByteOrderMarkAsString) {

        fmt.Printf("Found leading Byte Order Mark sequence!\n")
        
        s = strings.TrimPrefix(s, ByteOrderMarkAsString)
    }
    fmt.Printf("after: '%v' (len=%v)\n", s, len(s)) 
}
```

Other "strings" functions should work as well.

And this is what prints out:

```
before: ' is a string that starts with a Byte Order Mark (len=50)'
Found leading Byte Order Mark sequence!
after: ' is a string that starts with a Byte Order Mark (len=47)'
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

We used the [transform](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/text/transform) package to read CSV files (which may have been saved from Excel in UTF8, UTF8-with-BOM, UTF16) as follows:

```
import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "golang.org/x/text/encoding"
    "golang.org/x/text/encoding/unicode"
    "golang.org/x/text/transform"
    "io"
}

// BOMAwareCSVReader will detect a UTF BOM (Byte Order Mark) at the
// start of the data and transform to UTF8 accordingly.
// If there is no BOM, it will read the data without any transformation.
func BOMAwareCSVReader(reader io.Reader) *csv.Reader {
    var transformer = unicode.BOMOverride(encoding.Nop.NewDecoder())
    return csv.NewReader(transform.NewReader(reader, transformer))
}
```

We are using Go 1.18.

Answer (score 3):

There's no standard way of doing this in the Go core packages. Follow the Unicode standard.

[Unicode Byte Order Mark (BOM) FAQ](http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#BOM)

Comment: If I were generating all the files and streams myself, I would of course follow the Unicode standard to the letter. But like many people in the world, I'm stuck consuming data produced by somebody else.