# ingest csv space before field name

Tags: go

I have a weird problem I have this CSV

```
NAME,AGE,CITY
Bob,12,London
James,18,London
Joe,55,Manchester
Simon,21,Manchester
```

And the below code. But when I ingest the file, it comes with a space before the first field name (like below)

[image]

Below I have tried a string trim and a string replace but neither have worked. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
func main() {
    var files []string

    root := "C:\\Users\\kiera\\OneDrive\\Documents\\golang\\df\\filewalk\\csvs"
    
    err := filepath.Walk(root, func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        files = append(files, path)
        return nil
    })
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    for _, file := range files {
        //open the file
        openfile, _ := ioutil.ReadFile(file)

        //cast byte slice as string
        contents := string(openfile)

        //get rid of whitespace
        contents = strings.TrimSpace(contents)
        contents = strings.ReplaceAll(contents, " NAME", "NAME")
        fmt.Println(contents)
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code just reads the raw data, it isn't doing any CSV processing at all. If that is the literal code you're executing, then your input file has some blank (but not a literal space) character before the first label.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you reply. Do you know how I would handle that?

Comment: That depends on what "handle that" means to you. I would start by understanding the input file. What data does it contain?

Comment: The CSV contents are exactly as I pased at the top of my question - so definitely no space

Comment: There are three, and only three, possibilities: 1. That is not the literal CSV input. 2. That is not the literal output of your program. 3. The program you pasted is not the program you've executed.  If you've faithfully reproduced the code, then I'd say the most likely explanation is that you are mistaken about the contents of the input file. You can see, with that literal input, and that literal code, the output has no space: https://play.golang.org/p/6WOepXDUUvt

Comment: Gah so frustrating! I'm not sure why this is happening!

Comment: Use `fmt.Printf("%q\n", contents)` to find out what you actually have.

Comment: "\ufeffNAME... WEIRD!

Comment: what is your IDE, sometimes hidden character has been added to start of the file, especially in windows.

Comment: I used notepad++ to make the csv file and I used visual studio to write the Golang script (on Windows)

Comment: It looks like notepad++ added a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).  Write code to strip the BOM or use an editor that better understands UTF-8.   See [reading files with a BOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21371673/reading-files-with-a-bom-in-go).

Comment: Thanks to all for the comments and help, its working now! If someone adds it as an answer, I'll mark it as answered :)

Comment: `"\ufeffNAME... WEIRD!` -- Yep, as I predicted--a non-space whitespace as the first character. :) Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you use notepad++, notepad, netbeans or etc if you save the file as utf-8
it add hidden character (BOM) in the beginning of the file.
just change your IDE or disable BOM.
for example in notepad++ you can do follow this instructions https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-remove-bom-any-textxml-file

Mostly this problem happened in windows.

Comment: Thanks a lot again!!