# Using different readers sequentially on a file

Tags: csv, go

I'm parsing a specific type of data file which is very much like a csv file except that it has some extra header lines (which makes it, as a whole, not valid csv). Although I can write a decent parser using the bufio.Scanner reader, I'd really like to make use of the encoding/csv package reader once I'm done with scanning the header lines. My problem is that I'm not sure what is the best way to pass along the remainder of the unread lines to the csv reader. Currently I'm using an io.Pipe like this

```
// s is the bufio.Scanner which has finished scanning the header lines
r,w := io.Pipe()
go func() {
    // Flush scanner into pipe
    for s.Scan() {
        fmt.Fprintln(w, s.Text())
    }
    w.Close()
}()
c := csv.NewReader(r)
```

and it seems to work, but I'm wondering if there are any gotchas with this or if there's a more elegant way to pass a partially read io stream to another reader. Also, I don't think I could use the above method if my csv section was first (i.e. if I needed to parse non-csv lines after the csv-like part) because flushing with csv.Read calls would generate errors.

Comment: The only risk is if you read too much data from the reader, before passing it to `csv.NewReader`.  Say you read 100 bytes, and only need 50 of them, then the other 50 bytes probably contain data that `csv.Reader` needs. You can remedy this with [`io.MultiReader`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#MultiReader): `csv.NewReader(io.MutliReader(bytes.NewReader(unusedBytes), r)))`

Comment: To add to Flimzy's comment, that's a risk if you use any reader that uses a buffer internally - i.e., your own code may not read too far, but the reader still might.

Comment: Thanks, that's really useful. Incidentally, I also found that I can manipulate, to a certain extent, the csv parsing by changing the FieldsPerRecord variable in the course of parsing the file, so in this particular case I could get away without having to use a bufio Scanner to get through the header lines.

Comment: I came across another interesting scenario requiring sequential readers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21371673/reading-files-with-a-bom-in-go) . In this case it seems the solution (one of the popular ones) is to simply pass the bufio reader on to the next NewReader call. I suspect this wouldn't work with the bufio.Scanner (in my example) due to the buffering, but I'm not sure.